# how to judge an element's previous or next element exist with jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, element

suppose I have an `<ul>`
:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="test"></li>
</ul>
```

How can I judge the `.test` have its next element with jquery ?
like this?:

```
if ($("li.test").next()) { …… }
```

the strange thing is that ,even I write like above:

```
if ($("li.test").next()) {alert("true");}
```

it still alert "true",but as you see,there is no element next to it ?why this happened?

Or what I can do is

```
        for (i = 0; i < $("li").length; i++) {
            if ($("li").eq(i).hasClass("test")) {
                if (i == $("li").length - 1) {
                    alert("true");
                }
            }
        }
```

presently this could solve my problem,but is there a easy way?

thank you

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A jQuery selection will always evaluate to boolean `true` (as in an `if` statement).  This is because it is not a native Javascript type -- it is an object.

You need to check the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property of the selection.  If it is empty, this will be `0` and will evaluate to `false`, so the `if` will not pass. If it is not empty, it will be a positive integer and will therefore evaluate to `true`, so the conditional will pass.

```
if ($("li.test").next().length) { …… }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
if ($("li.test").next().length > 0) { ... }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kfsku/

Answer (score 2):

`$("li.test").next().length`;

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nFSjz/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the length property.

```
if ($("li.test").next().length) {
  //has next 
} else {
  //last elem
}
```

Keep in mind that jQuery usually returns itself so you can chain. Getting the `length` property of that object will give you the information