# If element does not have parent with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent

I am trying to create an if statement in jQuery for elements that have a parent with a specific class.

This is what I've come up with so far but it's not right.

```
if(!$(".myElem").parents(".myDiv")) {
    console.log("test")
};
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to judge an element's previous or next element exist with jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685685/how-to-judge-an-elements-previous-or-next-element-exist-with-jquery) -- same problem, even if the direction is a bit different.

Comment: Title does not match question. Title : "If element does NOT have", question: " elements that have"

Comment: Thanks @Narek... I had done a search for this but it didn't come up with that one... works a treat though.

Comment: It is unclear if you want to check only direct parents or all parents.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `length` to check it there are elements in the selector, and `closest()` would be better than `parents()` as it stops once it finds a match:

```
if(! $(".myElem").closest(".myDiv").length ) {
    console.log("has no parent with the class .myDiv")
}
```

Comment: Closest will find not only direct parents, but will search up until find one.

Answer (score 6):

If you are testing whether the element with class `myElem` has a direct parent with class myDiv use the following test

```
if(!$(".myElem").parent().hasClass("myDiv")) {
    console.log("test")
};
```

Comment: here .hasClass() would be better option than .is()

Answer (score 3):

```
if($(".myElem").parent().hasClass(".myDiv")) {
    console.log("has a parent with the class .myDiv")
}
else
{
    console.log("no parent class .myDiv found")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the only solution that works if $('.myElem') has more than one element is the one from Zoltan

see the example here

```js
 var takeElements = $('.myElement').filter(function(){
   return $(this).closest('.bannedAncestors').length === 0
 });
 
 takeElements.css('color','green');
 
 var bannedElements = $('.myElement').filter(function(){
   return $(this).closest('.bannedAncestors').length !== 0
 });
 
 bannedElements.css('color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bannedAncestors">
  <div> number of nested element don't matters
    <div class="myElement">
      don't take this child since it has an ancestor we don't want
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="myElement">
      but this one is ok
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should select those elements that have got class myElem with a parent that has a class myDiv:

```
$(".myElem").filter(function(elem) {
    return $(this).parents(".myDiv").length
});
```

or this should select those elements that have got class myElem and does not have a parent that has a class myDiv:

```
$(".myElem").filter(function(elem) {
    return !$(this).parents(".myDiv").length
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
   if($("#child").parent("span#parent").length > 0)
   {
          console.log("parent is span");

   }
   else {
          console.log("parent is not span or no parent");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to use `.closest()` if you know the classname of the child.

```
if(!$('yourtag.childClass').closest('yourParentTag').hasClass('classname')){
    console.log('does not exist');
}
```