# Getting the next image and previous image from an gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to code my own image gallery using `html` `css` `jquery`. I have a modal window to show the clicked in images. Inside my modal window I have a previous and next button.

My question is how can i show the previous images or next images when someone click that button.

Here's my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TSc8E/8/)

jquery code i am using to show clicked in images.

```
$(function(){
$('.gallery a').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault( );
    var imgPath = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.gallery-overlay').show()
    .find('.gallery-image').attr('src',imgPath);
    return false;
    });
```

});

Comment: the next and prev buttons are in modal window. for modal window to appear click on first images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your jQuery.

Declare a variable current image in your function and keep current image saved in that variable. Update the variable whenever current image is changed.

## [Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TSc8E/10/)

Click on the second image in the images and see the prev and next image then.

```
$('.gallery-control-previous').click(function(){
        var imgPath = current_img.prev().attr('href');
        current_img = current_img.prev();
        $('.gallery-overlay').show().find('.gallery-image').attr('src',imgPath);
});
$('.gallery-control-next').click(function(){
        var imgPath = current_img.next().attr('href');
        current_img = current_img.next();
        $('.gallery-overlay').show().find('.gallery-image').attr('src',imgPath);
});
```

If you have understood this answer, add checks to the code showing next, prev elemments only when they exist.

You can find how to do that,

## [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685685/how-to-judge-an-elements-previous-or-next-element-exist-with-jquery)..

## Updated.

Get the first child of next row, and pass that.

```
$('.gallery-control-next').click(function(){

        if(current_img.next().length){
            current_img = current_img.next();
        }else{
            current_img = current_img.parents(".row").next(".row").find("a:first");
        }
        var imgPath = current_img.attr('href');
        $('.gallery-overlay').show().find('.gallery-image').attr('src',imgPath);
    });
```

Comment: it is having some kind of bug. check this fiddle. i have added image link in all link. the next button doesn't work after 3 click. http://jsfiddle.net/TSc8E/12/

Comment: @Shubendra That's why I updated my answer. You need to check if the next and prev elements exist. After 3 click, all the images have been shown, so that causes the bug. You see one row has 3 images only.

Comment: after three click as the images in first row ends. it should show images from the bottom row

Comment: @OptimusPrime one more question, is there a better way to do all this? like currently i am putting all my images in a folder and providing a url of the image. will it be better if i store images in a database and retrieve images from database. i want a better techinque so that my webpage will load very fast

Comment: @Shubendra Also you may see in the same way, if the next row exists, if it doesn't you may go to the first row( hint - parents(?).find(".row:first")), then go to its first image or show the user no more images. Well you should be able to do it from here.

Comment: check this out. i finished it. http://jsfiddle.net/TSc8E/13/ please have a look at it and tell me if the coding can be improved any further?

Comment: @OptimusPrime can i use ajax here to load the next and prev image. will this enhance performance(i.e minimise loading time)?

Comment: @Shubendra I already answered this question. IMO, if there are too many images, which will not be loaded before the modal window, then you may use ajax. But if you are loading them before modal window too, then there is no such need. Since images are cached by the browser. And I looked at your fiddle. You must add a close or esc button to your modal window. Coding part is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have added `img_no` to each a tag to identify the current active image and get next or previous image

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/z9fc6/2)

```
$(function () {
    $('.gallery a').click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var imgPath = $(this).attr('href');
        var img_no = $(this).attr('img_no');
        $('.gallery-overlay').show()
            .find('.gallery-image').attr('src', imgPath).attr('img_no', img_no);
        return false;
    });
});
i = 1;
$('.row a img').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('img_no', i);
    $(this).parents('a').attr('img_no', i);
    i++;
});
images_length = i - 1;
console.log(images_length);
$('.gallery-control-next').click(function () {
    var img_no = $(this).parent().parent().find('.gallery-image').attr('img_no');
    img_no++;
    if (img_no > images_length) {
        img_no = 1;
    }
    $('.row a').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('img_no') == img_no) {
            imgPath = $(this).attr('href');
        }
    });
    $('.gallery-imagebox img').attr('src', imgPath).attr('img_no', img_no);
});
$('.gallery-control-previous').click(function(){
    var img_no = $(this).parent().parent().find('.gallery-image').attr('img_no');
    img_no--;
    if (img_no <= 0) {
        img_no = images_length;
    }
    $('.row a').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('img_no') == img_no) {
            imgPath = $(this).attr('href');
        }
    });
    $('.gallery-imagebox img').attr('src', imgPath).attr('img_no', img_no);
});
```

Comment: thanks tushar. it is working properly. i have one more problem. the image size will be large enough. and the browser may take time to download the next and prev image. i want to show some .gif image while the browser loads the image. and after it finish loading i want to display the final image. can you tell me how to achieve this

Comment: one more question, is there a better way to do all this? like currently i am putting all my images in a folder and providing a url of the image. will it be better if i store images in a database and retrieve images from database. i want a better techinque so that my webpage will load very fast.

Comment: Well, mine is shorter and easier to understand. :) But +1 for you. ;)